# What difference does it make when I use terminal or integrated terminal (IntelliJ IDE CE) to install jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, intellij-idea, terminal, ide

I've been trying to wrap my head around this Jenkins open source. I have never used Jenkins before. And after installing it using IntelliJ IDE, I realised that before installing it, you need to install Java. Since, I've installing it using IntelliJ, I'm hoping it works.

I was trying to install Jenkins on macOS. But I used IDE Terminal. The official doc says to install a java version(no clue which one) but they do not mention an IDE. I wonder whats the difference between the two.

Comment: An IDE is an integrated development environment. It may bring its own Java, or may require one. Jenkins, like many other programs, does not bring its own Java environment, so you need to install one first. I'd do that, e.g., with homebrew, instead of relying on the IDE's JDK, so that you can uninstall or upgrade the IDE without any impact on Jenkins. I'd suggest a web search on these things or on how to set up Java. Also check [ask].

Comment: You can find the Java support restrictions for Jenkins [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/platform-information/support-policy-java/).

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference, the IDE uses the native or default console of the operating system you are working on, it even respects configurations such as paths and environment variables.

Hope this help you, regards.